# set 2 reminder date using excel vba / conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to learn VBA in excel.

Here is my column structure.

```
 G            H                   I                  J             K       
 Email Sent   Email Sent date     Remainder 1        Remainder-2   Client Reply
    Yes            05-Aug-2019
```

Once my email sent Marked Yes and Email sent date was available automatically Reminder 1 (6 Working days) date and reminder 2 (9 working days) date should appear with colour code for Reminder 1 it should be orange and reminder 2 it should be Yellow

Currently I am trying with Conditional formatting but that is not helping me what I am looking for.

I tried the below code but I am not seeing the result. What am I doing wrong?

```
=AND(H2<>””,H2<TODAY()+7)
```

I have tried the below formula for adding dates

```
=IF(G215="Yes",WORKDAY(H215,6),K215="Yes""")
```

the above code was working perfectly fine but only problem is if client Reply column value select Yes those date should clear

Comment: In this `=AND(H2<>””,H2<TODAY()+7)` formula you got the double quotes wrong. It should be `""`. It currently also doesn't check for `Yes` in `G2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will solve your problem using Excel formulas only and not VBA. It is possible to solve the problem using VBA, but it seems simpler to solve using formulas and conditional formating only.

In column I (row 5, as example):

```
=IF(K5<>"yes";IF(G5="yes";WORKDAY(H5;6);"");"")
```

In column J (row 5, as example):

```
=IF(K5<>"yes";IF(G5="yes";WORKDAY(H5;9);"");"")
```

(Please note that I use semicolon instead of ony commas as separators, so you should adapt it to your Excel)

To format as Orange and Yellow each cell, you can use Conditional Formating:

Format only cells that contain -> Cell value | not equal to | = ""

Use the Conditional Formatting in columns I and J changing the cell fill.

Results when there is anything but "yes" in column K:
[The Conditional Formatting activates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS27c.jpg)

Results when there is "yes" in column K:
[The Conditional Formatting deactivates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3TOW.jpg)

Conditional Formatting (use one rule for each column):
[Cond. Form. example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMqPl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your explanation before your code I have completed my code.

below code is for 6 days

```
=IF(K341="Yes","0",IF(G341="Yes",(WORKDAY(H341,6)),"0"))
```

Below code is for 9 days

```
 =IF(K341="Yes","0",IF(G341="Yes",(WORKDAY(H341,9)),"0"))
```